# Как сделать чтоб в Html не отображалось поле модели которого нет

Tags: python, html, django, django-model

Как сделать чтоб в Html не отображалось поле модели которого нет

Comment: Задавая такого рода вопрос, у вас не возникает ощущения того, что читающим его совершенно не будет понятно, что вы подразумеваете? Неужели так сложно сформулировать минимальный понятный контекст?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать условные выражения в html-шаблонах Django для проверки наличия тех или иных полей формы. Пример:

```html
{% if model.value %}
    <p>{{ model.value }}</p>
{% else %}
    <p>value в модели отсутсвует</p>
{% endif %}
```